# Exiting Canada with another passport and exit information

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, canada, borders

I have recently read that, as of summer 2020, the government of Canada collects the exit information on its citizens when they cross the border.

However, how does the government track the citizens of Canada with dual citizenship who exit Canada on a *foreign* passport? The government probably has no information on foreign passports so how can it match (to its citizens) and record (accordingly) the outbound border crossings?

Comment: I don't think tracking Canadian citizens is the primary purpose, by far. They are probably far more interested in foreigners, to track overstays and the like for temporary visitors, or actual presence in Canada for those on the citizenship track, and so on. Nevertheless, based on data such as names + place and date of birth they can probably match a lot of people even if they use different passports. What is the scenario you are actually worried about?

Answer (score 2):

According to this :

https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/btb-pdf/eedcu-cudes-eng.html

Exit data includes biographic information such as:

- first name
- middle name(s)
- last name
- date of birth
- citizenship or nationality
- gender
- **travel document type, number and name of the country that issued the travel document**

So, I assume it'll get your foreign passport ID.

Comment: Then will they match it to the Canadian passport?